# EF Code first : set optional one to one relationship with data annotation

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I've the following situation I try to solve : I've 2 tables, a Course table with some fields and a CourseDescription table which is optional (so Course **may** have a CourseDescription but CourseDescription **must** have a Course). I'm trying to set this up. So far, here's what I have :

```
public class Course
{
    [Key, Column("Key_Course")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual CourseDescription CourseDescription { get; set; }
}

public class CourseDescription
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Course")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string PreRequis { get; set; }
    public int CoursesID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CoursesID")]
    public Course Course { get; set; }
}
```

This "works" meaning that EF doesn't complains about my model but the relation is not properly done because EF associate the PK of CourseDescription with the PK of Course. In my database, this is not the case (ex : CourseDescription.ID=1 is associated with CourseDescription.CoursesID=3, not 1).

Is there a way to fix that with data annotation ? I know I can use the fluent API but I don't want to override the model building just for that (unless there's no other way).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think you have two choices:

- **Configure an one to many relationship**

  If you want to map the FK of the relationship between `Course` and `CourseDescription`, and you don't want to declare that FK property as Key of the `CourseDescription` entity, then, you don't have other choice that configure an one-to-many relationship. In that case your model would be like this:

  ```
  public class Course
  {
   [Key, Column("Key_Course")]
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<CourseDescription> CourseDescriptions { get; set;}
  }

  public class CourseDescription
  {
   [Key]
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
   public string PreRequis { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("Course")]
   public int CourseID { get; set; }
   public Course Course { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- **Configure an one-to-one relationship but not map the FK of the
  relationship**

  The only way that EF lets you map the FK in an one-to-one relationship is when the FK is declared as a PK too, so if you want to have diferent Ids in both entities and you want to stablish an one-to-one relationship, then you could do something like this:

  ```
  public class Course
  {
   [Key, Column("Key_Course")]
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public CourseDescription CourseDescription { get; set;}
  }

  public class CourseDescription
  {
   [Key]
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
   public string PreRequis { get; set; }

   [Required]
   public Course Course { get; set; }
  }
  ```

  And work with the navigations properties.

Comment: Ok, I understand that what I need is not possible on a one-to-one relation. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should not use ForeignKey attribute for ID property of CourseDescription class as you don't want to have an association between primary keys. Try to remove it.

**Edit:** It looks like I misunderstood the question previous time.

You can have your CourseDescription this way.

```
public class CourseDescription
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Course")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string PreRequis { get; set; }
    public Course Course { get; set; }
}
```

In this case you don't need to have CoursesID field. Entities will be connected by primary keys.

Comment: If I remove it, I got an error : "Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types ...". Any help ?

Comment: My problem is that promary keys are different. I know it's a bit wierd but it's the way the DB is structured. That's why I've the courseID field in my CourseDescription entity.